# Random noise and i.i.d's

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random

In a book it is written that the quantity $\epsilon(\theta)$, called random noise, can be assumed to be i.i.d's when it does not depend on $\theta$. When it depends on $\theta$ it is said that the i.i.d assumption can't be made now. What is the meaning of it ?

Comment: What is $\theta$ exactly? If you can use different $\theta$'s in the expression then $\epsilon(\theta)$ can't be identically distributed.

Comment: @PA6OTA: why ? $\epsilon$ is a function from a set to a set of random variables. If all the random variables in the set are i.i.d then the random noise depends on $\theta$ but i.i.d's.

Comment: it depends on what exactly is $\epsilon(\theta)$. E.g. if $\epsilon(\theta) = A \theta$ then the distribution is not i.d.

Comment: Which book? $ $